# Why is my hierachy slicer not working when clicked in powerbi?

Tags: powerbi

If I am clicking on any levels in my hierarchy slicer in powerbi, my other dashboard visuals are not changing

I want all the levels in my hierarchy to work fine, as in If I am clicking on any value in a hierarchy, it should show me the visuals for that particular level

Comment: You need to provide more detail than that.